# In C# win forms , form should come full screen

Tags: c#, winforms

In C# windows application I need to set the form size maximum so that when ever i run the program it should show full.

In properties were should i set?

Comment: When I run the form , the form should set to full screen.

Comment: no, I didn't ask what you want to do, it's obvious from the question, but what did you already try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This topic can help you do this : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16618/How-To-Make-a-Windows-Form-App-Truly-Full-Screen-a

```
myFormsApp.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

Comment: i dont need when I click on button, i need when i run the application the form should maximise to full screen completely

Comment: There's no button clicked here.